# C - GTK - g_application_quit

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a problem with quitting a gtk application. The function call of g_application_quit results in the subsequent error:

```
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_application_quit: assertion 'G_IS_APPLICATION (application)' failed
```

The code snippet looks like this:

```
g_signal_connect(app_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(g_application_quit), app);
```

I tried this also, but still throws the same error:

```
g_signal_connect(app_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(g_application_quit), G_APPLICATION(app));
```

The app got initialized as:

```
GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("my.ne.sweeper", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to connect `g_application_quit` to window's `destroy` signal explicitly if You are using `G_APPLICATION`, it is done automatically.

Here goes the minimalistic example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer data) {
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new("your.app.name", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: the thing is, that I need the g_application_quit not only for the windows destroy but also for quitting the application through a menu option. Is there any way to do it with g_application_quit or how am I supposed to close the application properly?
ty

Comment: @Morpheus: it is perfectly valid to call `g_application_quit` from the menu action handler, you just don't need to connect it to the window's `destroy` signal. See the [example](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/application4/exampleapp.c) from `gtk+` tutorial.