# How do I quit a gtk application from a button click?

Tags: c, gtk, signals, gtk3

Im trying to quit an application from a button click. What I'm currently doing Segfaults.

I have tried calling `g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(app));` in main it still segfaults

Calling `gtk_widget_destroy(window);` also segfaults

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_application_add_window(app, GTK_WINDOW(window));
    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
    void shutdown()
    {
        g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(app));
    }
    g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(shutdown), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GApplicationFlags flags = G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE;
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.devab.daw", flags);
    GApplication *gapp = G_APPLICATION(app);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    g_application_run(gapp, argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    //g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(app));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - GTK - g\_application\_quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029025/c-gtk-g-application-quit)

Comment: @xing I need gtk3

Comment: @swordfish the possible dupplicate doesnt show how I can connect the signal. Thats why It was also not chosen as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using gtk3 and this compiles and works for me.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_application_add_window(app, GTK_WINDOW(window));
    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
    g_signal_connect_swapped(GTK_BUTTON(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GApplicationFlags flags = G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE;
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.devab.daw", flags);
    GApplication *gapp = G_APPLICATION(app);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    g_application_run(gapp, argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    //g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(app));
    return 0;
}
```

Move `destroy` outside `activate`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void destroy (GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(data));
}

void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_application_add_window(app, GTK_WINDOW(window));
    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
    g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(destroy), app);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GApplicationFlags flags = G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE;
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.devab.daw", flags);
    GApplication *gapp = G_APPLICATION(app);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    g_application_run(gapp, argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    //g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(app));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first one works but for the second one `g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(data));` segfaults

Comment: Now it the second works like a charm which I prefer than destroying the window

Comment: Windows registered with a `GtkApplication` should be of type `GtkApplicationWindow` instead of `GtkWindow`.